# Can't get title outside the image box on a simple bootstrap page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have simple page where I show logo and title bellow it in a shadowed box.

The problem is that I can't get the title outside the shadowed box.

This is the demo of the page

```css
.name {
 color: #1b1a1a;
  margin-top: 45px;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
}

.shadow {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.shadow img {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row equal">
            <div class="col-md-2 shadow">
              <img src="https://res-1.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_120,w_120,f_auto,b_white,q_auto:eco/v1483512777/dexdvfcyzuywzztqilod.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
              <div class="name">Cambian networks</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 shadow"> 
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Anbox_logo.png/120px-Anbox_logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"><br/>
              <div class="name"><p>Android</p></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want `Cambian networks` and `Android` outside(bellow) the box.

Here is also Jsfiddle demo `https://jsfiddle.net/7j9usa05/`

Comment: why you dont close the div shadow before  the second div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the shadow from the parent and give it to the `img` tag. That should solve your problem.

```css
.name {
  color: #1b1a1a;
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.shadow {
  padding: 10px;
  /* margin-right: 60px; */
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.shadow img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row equal">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="https://res-1.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_120,w_120,f_auto,b_white,q_auto:eco/v1483512777/dexdvfcyzuywzztqilod.png" class="img-responsive shadow" alt="Image">
      <div class="name">Cambian networks</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Anbox_logo.png/120px-Anbox_logo.png" class="img-responsive shadow" alt="Image">
      <div class="name">
        <p>Android</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to but "box-shadow" on the relevant element, in that case.
For above scenario, try putting the box-shadow on image only.
Updated fiddle at "https://jsfiddle.net/f14awjks/"
Relevant styles updates :

```
 .shadow {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.shadow img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML & CSS

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row equal">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="shadow">
              <img src="https://res-1.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_120,w_120,f_auto,b_white,q_auto:eco/v1483512777/dexdvfcyzuywzztqilod.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
                          </div>
              <div class="name">Cambian networks</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"> 
            <div class="shadow">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Anbox_logo.png/120px-Anbox_logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
                          </div>
              <div class="name"><p>Android</p></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xLg745s6/